# sqoop oozie write query result to a file

Tags: hadoop, oozie, sqoop

I have a current oozie job that queries an Oracle table and writes - overwrites the result on a hive query.
Now I need to prevent overwriting the hive table and save the existing data on that hive table.
For this I wanted to plan such steps:
1st step: Get record count running a "select count(*) from..." query and write it on a file.
2nd step: Check the count written in file.
3rd step: decision step whether or not 4th step will be applied.
4th step: Run the main query and overwrite the hive table.

My problem is I couldn't find anything on documentation and or examples regarding writing them on a file (I know import and export is the aim of sqoop) .
Does anyone know how to write the wuery result on a file?

Answer (score 1):

In theory:

1. build a **Pig** job to run the "count(*)" and dump the result to StdOut
   as if it was a Java property e.g. `my.count=12345`
2. in Oozie, define a Pig Action, with `<capture_output/>` flag, to run that job
3. then define a Decision based on the value for key `my.count` using
   the appropriate EL function

In practise, well, have fun!